# create a registration page in opencart for different group user

Tags: php, opencart

i am trying to create a registration page in opencart. i have just copied the registration files from controller/account and view/account files and  rename both files and change some codes inside and uploaded  them now form working fine as other normal form working. I also changed the form action.

Now i want this page user should be registered as whole sale ( a  customer group i have created in opencart which id is 2 i have checked in database)

any help pls!

thanks

Answer (score 6):

You simply can do above functionality using same form (if you dont know)

> Sales -> Customer -> Customer Group

add new customer group "Whole sale" and configure it's options

Now enable display on register form

> System -> Setting -> Option

under Account select "Default" & "Whole sale".

Now the "Select Group Option" appears on Register form.

If you want to do it in seperate form like you explained in question, you have to pass value from Register form `customer_group_id`

`Catalog\Model\Account\Customer::addCustomer()` checks for the customer group id

And you need to modify script (after content bottom script) to enable option regarding that group.

Comment: I already know the solution that you explained here. but there are  some changes needed in addcustomer class too. thanks for help :)